# How create contact forms in joomla?

Tags: joomla, forms

Please tell me if it is possible on joomla to display a form with a text field on the site, so that when it is filled in, a user is created, as well as an incoming message from this user? Using the standard features of civicrm, I managed to create only a form that creates a user, but I cannot attach a text field to this form. Apparently, the standard features do not allow this, or there are some nuances that I do not know about.
Here is what I was able to create https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiy5G.png
Below you need to add a text field that will contain the text of the letter. I cannot add it. Do not know how.
If I add activity / details to the profile, the form stops working.

Original text in russian:
Здравствуйте.
Скажите пожалуйста ли возможность на joomla, вывести на сайт форму с текстовым полем, так, что бы при её заполнении создавался пользователь, а так же входящее сообщение от этого пользователя?
Используя стандартные возможности civicrm, мне удалось создать только форму, которая создаёт пользователя, а вот текстовое поле прикрепить к этой форме мне не удается. Видимо стандартные возможности этого сделать не позволяют, либо есть какие-то нюансы, о которых я не знаю.
Вот то, что мне удалось создать https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiy5G.png
Ниже нужно добавить текстовое поле, которое будет содержать текст письма. Его я не могу добавить. Не знаю как.
Если в профиль добавляю активность/детали, то форма перестает работать.

Answer (score 1):

To add a Text Field to a Profile (which you can then use as a Contact Form) you need to go to Custom Fields, add a field set and then add your field.
Then go to your profile and add this field.
If you want users created then select the option in Advanced settings of the Profile to set this up.

Comment: Hello.
1. As soon as I add a phone number to the form, the text of the note stops updating every time I send a new letter. That is, the text of the old application is sent. The very first.
I cannot delete the phone number from the postal form, since I need it.

Comment: 2. Besides, it is not clear how to reflect this event on the main page of the system, in the report on incoming mail? After all, if for some reason the mail service that I use to send letters stops working, then I will not know that the person has filled out this form.

Comment: I tried to organize the output of recently changed contacts in the report, and bring it to the main page, to the dashboard, but it is impossible to filter the contacts in which the application was filled out. The simplest and most secure option would be to do it as originally planned. That is, create a contact + an incoming message, which would be displayed in the activity table, as an incoming message.

Comment: Your first comment doesn't really make sense to me and worries me that you have some set up incorrect. Perhaps add some screenshots to your Question to try and clarify what you are doing.

Comment: Upd 1 questions:
Original russian text:
Если создать форму в которой имеется поле с  адресом электронной почты, и текстом заявки, то при отправке одним и тем же пользователем каждой новой заявки, я получаю всегда новый текст во вкладке с заметками в профиле.

Если к этой форме добавить поле с номером телефона, то каждый раз, когда один и тот же пользователь отправляет новый текст заявки, я получаю в письме всегда содержимое первой заявки. 
Вот так: 
Первое письмо ​https://i.imgur.com/f1UFPny.png
Второе письмо https://i.imgur.com/nxWkPLk.png
Третье письмо https://i.imgur.com/eRii466.png

Comment: А на самом деле текст заявки каждый раз был разным: https://i.imgur.com/X6zmoAw.png
Эта проблема касается только той информации, которая попадает в заметки.

​Вся остальная информация меняется. С ней проблем нет.

Comment: Google translate:

If you create a form in which there is a field with an e-mail address and the text of the application, then when the same user sends each new application, I always receive a new text in the tab with notes in the profile.

Comment: If we add a field with a phone number to this form, then every time the same user sends a new application text, I always receive the contents of the first application in a letter.
Like this:
First letter https://i.imgur.com/f1UFPny.png
Second letter
https://i.imgur.com/nxWkPLk.png
Third letter
https://i.imgur.com/eRii466.png

But in fact, the text of the application was different each time: https://i.imgur.com/X6zmoAw.png
This problem concerns only the information that gets into the notes.

 All other information changes. There are no problems with her.

Comment: That last screenshot shows you are using NOTES for this. I have no familiarity of adding Notes via Profiles. We generally use Activities.

Comment: If I add an activity with the Activity type to the profile, the form stops working. The create mode disappears

Comment: maybe try this https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/activityprofile

Comment: Thank you petednz - fuzion!